# Does the Lenovo ThinkCentre K230 support large graphics cards?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express, thinkcentre

I am looking to buy a new desktop system, and have found the [Lenovo ThinkCentre K230](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883108209) (8 GB of RAM, Core 2 Quad Q8200). My main concern is if it will accept a full size graphics card like a Radeon HD 4890 or GTS 250.

Based on the following picture, there seems to be enough room in the case for for a bulky graphics card:

[image: picture here]

But the specs for it on [this site](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4833576&CatId=4927), for instance, say "PCI Express X16 Slots (Total): 1 Half Length". I am worried that because it is half length it will not accept large graphics cards, but this makes no sense - it is a huge case which looks like it could hold a large PCI-e card.

Can anyone give a definitive answer? Because it would be a perfect system for me, if only I could swap in a nice graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case looks big enough, but I don't like the position of the hard disk bays.

It could indeed be a problem to fit a full-length (312mm) graphics card.

[image]

The price is right, certainly a good deal there.

Comment: my personal opinion: should the hard disk bay constitute a problem, it would be gone in NO time, even if it takes an angle grinder to get rid of it. :)

Comment: As stated in the question, the PSU may be limiting graphics cards as well but, alas... if the drive bay can be removed it shouldn't be a problem. Browsing the reviews the disk seems to be from a bad batch though and it may not be eligible for a Win7 upgrade ^^

Comment: I did read that, hard drives are pretty cheap so I can always replace it, also even if there is not a windows 7 upgrade I have a full copy on hand. although I think some of the later reviews said that lenovo changed their policy on the upgrade.